# What is a 0 (zero) step?

Tags: officiating, basketball, terminology, technique, nba

I have been watching James Harden and his "creative" ways to take extra steps without being called for a travel.

One concept that he uses is a "0 step." I'm having a hard time figuring out what a 0 step is, not so much with the general concept in which it is a step before a player gathers his dribble, but with how it is enforced.

What is a 0 (zero) step with respect to how is it enforced?

Answer (score 1):

I can only respond with the FIBA not NBA view. FIBA travel rule was aligned to match NBA in 2017.

The zero step refers to the step taken when gaining control of the ball.
When dribbling, the zero step gathering happens as the ball is gathered in 2 hands or let it rest in 1 hand.

Similarly when moving and catching a ball.

Here is a link to a related Question with NBA reference
[NBA traveling - conflicting rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/20981/11802)